# SwiftUI | Сложные структуры данных обновляющие UI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Имею довольно сложную структуру данных, класс с большим количеством переменных, являющимися экземплярами других классов. В каждой из этих переменных есть `UInt16` значение и `String` get-set переменная, ответственная за форматированный ввод-вывод этих значений.

Значение внутри определённых экземпляров классов изменяются через `TextField` в UI программы, что работает, внутри других же изменяются в результате действий функции в одном из вложенных экземпляров, что не работает (соединены друг с другом с помощью `Binding`).

Настоящим решением является добавление `@Published var updater: Bool` переменной в основной класс и привязывание её в класс с функцией, с последующим вызовом `.toggle()` в конце работы. Но данное решение работает не совсем корректно, не говоря уже о том, что это вряд ли оно в какой-либо степени правильное.

Далее код основного класса:

```
class Computer: ObservableObject
{
    @Published var updater: Bool = false
    
    @Published var program: Program = Program()
    
    @Published var shift: Shift = Shift()
    @Published var accumulator: Accumulator = Accumulator()
    @Published var commandCounter: CommandCounter = CommandCounter()
    @Published var addressRegister: AddressRegister = AddressRegister()
    @Published var commandRegister: CommandRegister = CommandRegister()
    @Published var dataRegister: DataRegister = DataRegister()
    @Published var statusRegister: StatusRegister = StatusRegister()
    
    @Published var arithmeticLogicUnit: ArithmeticLogicUnit = ArithmeticLogicUnit()
    
    @Published var externalDevices: [ExternalDevice] = [ExternalDevice(), ExternalDevice(), ExternalDevice()]
    
    @Published var microCommandManager: MicroCommandManger = MicroCommandManger()
    
}
```

Классы, чьи экземпляры находятся в основном классе ничего не наследуют, их переменные ничем не обёрнуты, в некоторых из них есть `@Binding` переменные для получения необходимых данных. (Добавление `Binding` в переменные осуществляется в `init()` класса, который я опустил за ненадобностью)

Экземпляр основного класса добавлен к `View` как `.enviromentObject()`

Что именно нужно сделать с переменными, чтобы при изменения значений в экземплярах обновлялся UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

тебе нужно 2 инстанса - вьюха и модель.

вот пример модели

```
class ComputerViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var videocard: String = "RTX..."
    ///...........
}
```

вот пример вьюхи:

```
struct ComputerView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: BrowserViewModel
    var body: some View {
        //здесь ты обращаешся к model.videocard
        VStack{
           Text("сейчас стоит видяха: {model.videocard}")

           TextField($model.videocard)
        }
        
  
    }
}
```

важно понимать для работы то, что если ты хочешь коректной работы с вью-моделью -

1. viewModel должна быть обсервейбл и внутри вьюхи инстанс -- обсерведом.
2. для автообновления вьюхи все во viewModel должно быть структурами, а не обьектами класса.

других сложностей вроде нет.

код писал из головы непроверяя, так что могут быть мелкие синтаксические ошибки.

Comment: Проблема была не в изменении данных UI элементами, а в изменении данных с помощью функции класса.
Решение её уже нашёл.

Comment: Если правильно все реализовать -- так как я написал -- то не нужно будет вручную делать 'objectWillChange.send()'. И не важно с помощью чего именно меняется переменная - из функции класса или из юая.

Comment: Тебе приходится обновлять вручную все потому что ты делаешь обьект модели инстансом класса, а не структурой. (Про что говорил пункт 2 моего ответа.) Вот и используешь костыли. Лучше бы вчитался в мой ответ и сделал правильно.

Comment: Не понял из изначального ответа что ты именно имел в виду. Переделал всё на структуры, работает без ```objectWillChange.send()```. Предполагаю, что SwiftUI не отслеживает изменения значений по ссылкам, хранящимся в переменных экземпляра.

Comment: А он и не должен. Это архитектурная особенность свифт юая. Весь свифтЮай - это исключительно структуры. Это нужно для "однозначности" данных. Как только данные меняются хоть как-то, перерисовывается весь юай. Изменение данных по ссылочных типах отследить с достаточной однозначностью невозможно.