# Swiftui не обновляет View

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

View обновляется только примерно в 30% случаях...
Почему такое может быть? Может, переменная обновляется дольше, чем перестраивается View?
Как правильно сделать, чтобы при клике на В корзину сразу шло обновление этого View?

```
struct ToCart: View {
    let offer: Offer
    @StateObject var cart = Cart.shared
    var body: some View {
        if let index = cart.offers.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == offer.id}) {
            Text("In Cart")
        } else {
            Button(action: {
                cart.add(offer: offer)
            }) {
                Text("To Cart")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class Cart: ObservableObject {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    static let shared = Cart()
    @Published var offers = [CartOffer]()
    func add(offer: Offer, count: Int = 1) {

        if let cartOfferIndex = offers.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == offer.id}) {
            offers[cartOfferIndex].count += count
        } else {
            offers.append(CartOffer(id: offer.id, offer: offer, count: count))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что есть Ваш `CartOffer`?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [SwiftUI | Сложные структуры данных обновляющие UI](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1208760/swiftui-%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5-ui)

Answer (score 0):

CartOffer должен быть структурой если в двух словах.

Если нужно больше обьяснений - я отметил этот вопрос дубликатом - там есть обьяснения о том как должно быть все обустроено и в комментариях есть обьяснение почему. [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1208760/swiftui-Сложные-структуры-данных-обновляющие-ui](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1208760/swiftui-%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-ui)